# Compare tables and identify new or changed fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to SQL, would like to compare fields between a stg and src table. The identify any differences between the tables and assign transaction status of 'C' for change. Any new records will be set with 'A' for add.

STG_DM_CLIENT and SRC_DM_CLIENT

What is the best way to do it, would it be best to do a some form of union all. Unsure how to proceed, any assistance welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify new records by using NOT IN or NOT EXISTS

```
update STG_DM_CLIENT SET TransactionStatus = 'A' WHERE ID IN
     (select Id from STG_DM_CLIENT 
            where Id not in (select Id from SRC_DM_CLIENT))
```

Then, you can identify changed records by comparing fields:

```
update STG_DM_CLIENT SET TransactionStatus = 'C' WHERE ID IN
    (select STG_DM_CLIENT.Id from STG_DM_CLIENT 
        join SRC_DM_CLIENT on SRC_DM_CLIENT.Id = STG_DM_CLIENT.Id
        where (SRC_DM_CLIENT.Field1 != STG_DM_CLIENT.Field1
            OR SRC_DM_CLIENT.Field2 != STG_DM_CLIENT.Field2 ...))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update
  [STG]
set
  TransactionStatus = CASE WHEN [SRC].id IS NULL THEN 'A' ELSE 'C' END
from
  STG_DM_CLIENT  AS [STG]
left join
  SRC_DM_CLIENT  AS [SRC]
    ON [STG].id = [SRC].id -- Or whatever relates the records 1:1
WHERE
  [SRC].id IS NULL
  OR [STG].field1 <> [SRC].field1
  OR [STG].field2 <> [SRC].field2
  OR [STG].field3 <> [SRC].field3
  ...
  OR [STG].fieldn <> [SRC].fieldn
```

Comment: Hi, confused by the first line - WHEN [SRC].id IS NULL THEN 'A'. How will it be able to identify new client records, when your you've stated client_code = null then A. Please explain - might of misunderstood? Thank you in advance

Comment: If you LEFT JOIN data, you get ALL the records on the left table, even if a record doesn't exist for the right table.  This means that if a record exists in STG but not in SRC, all the SRC fields will be NULL.  Therefore, if SRC.id IS NULL, it doesn't exist in SRC, and the record in STG is to be added.